# How will i get the Date Time once the record has been opened in salesforce? I need this value to compare with LastModifiedDate in my Lwc component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Here is my JS file of LWC :

```
import { LightningElement, api,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
//import updateNotification from '@salesforce/apex/isUpdateNotification.updateNotification';
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getfetchListData from'@salesforce/apex/globalUtilityClass.globalUtilityClass_lwc';


export default class ObjectUpdateNotification extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track currentDate;
    @track filed;
    renderedCallback(){
        this.currentDate=new Date();
    }

    
@wire(getfetchListData,{
        ids:'$recordId',currentDate:'$currentDate'
    }) pageRef;
    wiredResult(result){ 
            if(result.data){
                ShowToastEvent();{
                const event = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Toast Info',
                    message: 'This record has been modified since you last loaded this page.',
                    variant: 'info',
                    mode: 'dismissable'
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(event);
            }   
        }     
    }
}

Here is a Apex Class used:
global with sharing class globalUtilityClass {
    public Date LastModifiedDate {get;set;}
    public Id pageId {get;set;}
    public String objectType {get;set;}
    public sObject thisObject{get;set;}
    
    public globalUtilityClass()
    {
        pageId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        string pageObjectType =  pageID.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        string queryString = 'SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate FROM ' + pageObjectType + ' WHERE Id = \'' + pageID + '\'';
        List<sObject> L = Database.query(queryString);
        LastModifiedDate = Date.Valueof(L[0].get('LastModifiedDate'));
    }
        @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static Boolean globalUtilityClass_lwc(id ids,DateTime currentDate){
        Boolean isTrue = false;
        List<Orders__c> ModifiedOrder = [Select ID, LastModifiedDate from Orders__c where ID = :ids];
        DateTime Lastmodifieddate1 = ModifiedOrder.get(0).LastModifiedDate;
        if (Lastmodifieddate1>currentDate)
        {
            isTrue =true;
            system.debug(isTrue);
        }
        return isTrue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the field LastViewedDate in the SOQL. This field is blank on creation and stamped with the date when the record is viewd the first time. And upon subsequent record views updated with the most recent view date.

```
List<Orders__c> ModifiedOrder = [Select ID, LastViewedDate , LastModifiedDate from Orders__c where ID = :ids];
```